# How to create ancestor of an entity (google datastore) using php?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-php-client

I am working on google datastore. I need to create a `Log` kind of entity having `user` entity as its parent. I am using [Google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library to integrate the api in php. I am succeed in creating entites. To insert an entity I'm using following functions.

```
/*
 *Function to insert the entity into the google datastore.
 */
function google_set_insert($data) {

  $field_set = $data['field_set'];
  $entity_kind = $data['entity_kind'];
  $entity_name = $data['entity_name'];

  $entity = google_create_entity($field_set, $entity_kind, $entity_name);
  $mutation = new Google_Service_Datastore_Mutation();
  $mutation->setInsert($entity);
  $req = new Google_Service_Datastore_CommitRequest();
  $req->setMode('NON_TRANSACTIONAL');
  $req->setMutations($mutation);
  return $req;
}
```

But I am unable to create the ancestor of an entity. Can you please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using the [Google Cloud PHP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-datastore-beta) client library (as long as you are not on GAE Standard).

You need to add the ancestor when you first create the entity, since it cannot be changed once initially written.

```
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;

$datastore = new DatastoreClient();

$key = $datastore->key('Person', 'Bob');
$key->ancestor('Parents', 'Joe');
$entity = $datastore->entity($key, [
    'firstName' => 'Bob',
    'lastName' => 'Testguy'
]);

echo $entity['firstName']; // 'Bob'
$entity['location'] = 'Detroit, MI';
```

See more in the documentation for [keys](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.24.0/datastore/key).

Comment: On GAE standard, you can use my PHP-GDS library, which also supports ancestors. https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds